# MediaWiki - Flagged for revision but no pending revisions

Tags: mediawiki, revision

I am the admin for a mediaWiki. I have made edits to a page in the wiki and during this editing I added a new `Template`.

In the edits to the wiki page I saw the below after saving

[image]

I have checked my `Special:PendingChanges` and its empty:
[image]

Why can't I save the edits to my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `Special:UnreviewedPages` instead, `PendingChanges` only lists pages which have a (non-current) reviewed revision. The messageyou saw is shown any time a page itself is fully reviewed but it uses an image or template that isn't.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Annoyingly I had to give myself editor permissions which I thought funny